# DeadLetterService in Jboss

Tags: java, jboss, dead-letter

We have application deployed in Jboss SOA platform.Performance point of view, we had commented out the DeadLetterService in jboss-esb.xml. So when any exception occurs or message is not delivered to 3rd party, it should not go to DLQ. But now we are getting the following error

```
********************************
2012-12-18 18:02:30,996 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/ServiceName].[HttpGateway]] (http-0.0.0.0-9032-14) Servlet.service() for servlet HttpGateway threw exception
org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.MissingServiceException: Registry details for service [JBossESB-Internal:DeadLetterService] could not be determined from the registry.
        at org.jboss.soa.esb.client.ServiceInvoker.post(ServiceInvoker.java:348)
********************************
```

It is taking around 5 min to send the response to 3rd party.We are trying to find out the reason for delay.

Can anyone know how the issue is related with "DeadLetterService"? or how can i reproduce the issue? or why 5 minute delay?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by turning off the DeadLetterService for performance reasons but since the call to this service is hard coded in ServiceInvoker it is not a good idea to remove the service entirely.

You can switch off its use by a property, either globally or per message.

> The DeadLetterService is turned on by default, however in the
>   jbossesb-properties.xml you could set org.jboss.soa.esb.dls.redeliver
>   to false to turn off its use. If you want to control this on a per
>   message basis then set the org.jboss.soa.esb.dls.redeliver property in
>   the specific Message properties accordingly. The Message property will
>   be used in preference to any global setting. The default is to use the
>   value set in the configuration file.

https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_SOA_Platform/5/html/ESB_Programmers_Guide/chap-SOA_ESB_Programmers_Guide-Advanced_Topics.html#idp10520576